# matlab figure is blank when running jar

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, executable-jar

I have written a matlab function(`myFunction`) that plots a simple graph. Using matlab JA builder I have created a jar file. I made a new project in eclipse and called the `myFunction` in the `main` method. It runs fine in eclipse. When I export the project to a runnable jar and run it, the matlab figure is blank(the frame appears with the buttons, but the graph is blank). Any thoughts on resolving this?

MATLAB

```
function myFunction()
%MYFUNCTION Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
a = [1:10];
b = [1:5:50];

plot(a,b);

end
```

Java

```
import take2.*;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;


public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleGraph sg = null;

    try {
        sg = new SimpleGraph();
        sg.myFunction();
    } catch (MWException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab won't display graphs properly in java 1.7. My eclipse was using 1.6(works fine) but my system was running 1.7. When running the jar from command line use:

```
java -version:1.6 -jar myJar.jar
```

The graph should then display properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem with the Matlab JAVA Builder is but have you tried making any debug statements in the Matlab function...

Other than that the [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) might be an option. Moreover, here is a [list](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html) with other ways to call Matlab from Java.

A last thought on the plot issue...If you just want display the plot, you can always save the plot and then load and display it from Java. I know....this isn't the most elegant solution but it will work.

Hope that helps, Stephan